# Link não funciona após load de <div>

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou fazendo um *login*, usando Ajax para enviar os dados para uma página PHP, que devolve com a resposta se o *login* foi ou não validado. Se estiver ok, eu atualizo uma `<div>` com os dados do usuário logado e exibo o avatar, sem dar o *refresh* na página, até ai tudo certo.

O problema que estou tendo, é que após a atualização dessa `<div>`, o link do avatar que abre um menu, simplesmente não funciona, apenas eu dando um <kbd>F5</kbd> ele volta a funcionar. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
$("#login").click(function(){
  username=$("#username").val();
  if (username == "") {
    $("#add_erro_login").html("Digite o usu&aacute;rio cadastrado");
    $("#username").focus();
    return false;
  }

  password=$("#password").val();
  if (password == "") {
    $("#add_erro_login").html("Digite a senha cadastrada");
    $("#password").focus();
    return false;
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "login.php",
    data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
    success: function(html){
        if(html=='true')
        {
            document.form1.loading.style.visibility = "hidden";
            $("#login-form").fadeOut("slow");
            $("#background-on-popup").fadeOut("slow");
            $("#perfil").fadeOut("fast");
            $("#perfil").load("perfil.php");
            $("#perfil").fadeIn("fast");
         }
        else 
        {
            document.form1.loading.style.visibility = "hidden";
            $("#add_erro_login").html("Usu&aacute;rio ou Senha inv&aacute;lido");
        }
    },
    beforeSend:function()
    {
        document.form1.loading.style.visibility = "visible";
        $("#add_erro_login").html("");
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Topo do site, ande são exibidos os dados do usuário e o seu avatar

```
<div id="perfil">
  <?php 

  if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
  }

  If(isset($_SESSION['avatar'])) {
      $avatar = $_SESSION['avatar'];
  }
  Else {
      $avatar = "usuario.png";
  }

  if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    echo "<div class='perfil-box'><div id='img-avatar'><a href='#'><img src='fotos/$avatar' width='40' height='40'></a></div><br>";
    echo "<div class='perfil-texto'><h1>Bem vindo,</h1><h2>" .$_SESSION['nome']. ' ' .$_SESSION['sobrenome']."</h2></div></div>";
    echo "<span class='seta-baixo'></span>";
  }
  ?>
</div>
```

O div id='img-avatar' é que mostra e oculta o menu

```
    $("#img-avatar").click(function(){

    if(document.getElementById("menu-perfil").style.display=="") {
        document.getElementById("menu-perfil").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("seta-baixo").style.display = "inline";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("menu-perfil").style.display=="none") {
        document.getElementById("menu-perfil").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("seta-baixo").style.display = "inline";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("menu-perfil").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("seta-baixo").style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

Abs

Comment: Ou seja, seu problema é em `$("#perfil").load("perfil.php")`? O que o avatar tem a ver com isso? Pode mostrar uma versão reduzida do seu HTML? Confira o guia [**Como fazer exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Os componentes html que são atualizados depois da requisição Ajax, são na verdade recriados. Assim, as associações de funções JavaScript (por exemplo no evento `onclick`) são perdidas. Você tem que associar novamente a função ou associá-la de um jeito que ela seja refeita durante durante a recriação do componente html. Se você explicar melhor o teu código e mostrar também o código html, podemos ajudar mais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A associação entre o evento click de `#img-avatar` e a função JavaScript que exibe o menu é perdida quando o componente é recriado (ele é recriado na requisição Ajax).

Para que a função seja novamente associada ao evento click depois de o componente ser recriado, atribua-a usando o método [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) do JQuery.

Por exemplo:

```
$(document).on('click', '#img-avatar', function () {
    if(document.getElementById("menu-perfil").style.display=="") {
        document.getElementById("menu-perfil").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("seta-baixo").style.display = "inline";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("menu-perfil").style.display=="none") {
        document.getElementById("menu-perfil").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("seta-baixo").style.display = "inline";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("menu-perfil").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("seta-baixo").style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

Comment: Caffé, cara é isso mesmo!!! Muito obrigado...

Comment: Você sabe se o Session do PHP tb são perdidos? Porque agora, dentro desse menu, tem um tópico pro usuário mudar seu avatar, e sem dar o F5 ele esta trazendo o $_SESSION['usuario'] como VAZIO. Tem alguma relação?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, @Ricardo. Não manjo de PHP. Se você postar uma nova pergunta provavelmente a comunidade poderá ajudar.